# Where is texture tool located in Xcode 4.3.1?

Tags: xcode, textures, xcode4.3

I have installed Xcode 4.3.1.

I am looking for the "texturetool" that is used for converting PNG's to PVR files.

According to :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TextureTool/TextureTool.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH108-SW1

The file is located at :

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool

But since I installed Xcode from the app store, /Developer doesn't exist! This is the new "app" version of Xcode.

EDIT: Ok, I found it here: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin

What should I do so that I can access the tool without typing the full path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access that tool without typing in the full path, you can add that longish path to your "`PATH`" environment variable.

You can find some ways to modify `PATH` in the [answers to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/345201/is-it-possible-to-set-path-on-mac-os-x-lion-without-restarting).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did something like : sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer so that I could access xcodebuild without having to type the path, is there something similar I could do to access the iPhone tools?